# Join in CARTO - Relate tables 1:M

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I'm trying to make a join between two tables in SQL with 1: M relation. A table `ejecutado_unificado_2018` is a dataset without geographic information and the dataset `sectores_limpieza_2018` comes from a shapefile. When I do the join, I do not recognize the `cartodb_id` or the geometry when I use `the_geom_webmercator`. I would like to know my mistake.

```
SELECT sectores_limpieza_def2.the_geom AS the_geom_webmercator,
       sectores_limpieza_def2.cartodb_id
FROM ejecutado_unificado_2018
JOIN sectores_limpieza_def2
  ON sectores_limpieza_def2.codigo=ejecutado_unificado_2018.codigo
```

Answer (score 2):

CARTO is going to return errors if any of the mandatory fields -`cartodb_id`, `the_geom` and `the_geom_webmercator` are not present in the `SELECT`. So in order to make your query work, you need to add them:

```
SELECT 
  b.the_geom,
  b.the_geom_webmercator,
  a.cartodb_id
FROM 
  ejecutado_unificado_2018 a
JOIN 
  sectores_limpieza_def2 b ON a.codigo = b.codigo
```

Also, notice that there were also two key mistakes. On the one hand, you were selecting the `cartodb_id` from the geometry table. As far I understood, you wanted to keep every row from your non-geometry table. So for your use case, the proper way to do it is adding the id of this former table (and any thematic fields you need). And on the other, you were renaming `the_geom` to `the_geom_webmercator` without any transformation. For future reference, [you should use `ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Finally, notice that there is [a join analysis available in BUILDER UI called `Add columns from second table`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/data-and-sql/adding-rows-and-columns-in-the-data-view/). If using this, you will not need to apply SQL.